# Find IP address string in multiple text files and add it to the relevant rows in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-2.7

I have multiple txt files with below details:

> Text File1:

```
 Id                = 0005      
 Cause          = ERROR      
 Code     = 307      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:16:48      
 Severity      = WARNING      
 Severity Code = 5      
 Id                = 0006      
 Cause          = FAILURE      
 Code     = 517      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:19:47      
 Severity      = MINOR      
 Severity Code = 4  ip[10.1.1.1
```

> Text File2:

```
 Id                = 0007      
 Cause          = ERROR      
 Code     = 307      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:16:48      
 Severity      = WARNING      
 Severity Code = 5      
 Id                = 0008      
 Cause          = FAILURE      
 Code     = 517      
 Event Time              = 2020-11-09 10:19:47      
 Severity      = MINOR      
 Severity Code = 4  
 ip[10.1.1.3
```

I want to see below result if it is possible:

```
Id          Cause       Code     Event Time             Severity        Severity Code    ip
0005        ERROR       307     2020-11-09 10:16:48     WARNING         5               10.1.1.1
0006        FAILURE     517     2020-11-09 10:19:47     MINOR           4               10.1.1.1
0007        ERROR       307     2020-11-09 10:16:48     WARNING         5               10.1.1.3
0008        FAILURE     517     2020-11-09 10:19:47     MINOR           4               10.1.1.3
```

Besides now at the moment I have the below result and I don't know how it would be possible to add IP as the other column.

```
  Id          Cause       Code     Event Time             Severity        Severity Code
0005        ERROR       307     2020-11-09 10:16:48     WARNING         5
0006        FAILURE     517     2020-11-09 10:19:47     MINOR           4
0007        ERROR       307     2020-11-09 10:16:48     WARNING         5               
0008        FAILURE     517     2020-11-09 10:19:47     MINOR           4
```

Code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("(.+?)=(.+?)\s{2,}")
data = []
item = {}

with open("data.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for m in pattern.finditer(line):
            key, value = [m.group(i).strip() for i in [1,2]]
            
            if key == "Id":
                if item:
                    data.append(item)
                item = {"Id": value}
            else:
                item[key] = value

    data.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Regex: `.*ip\[((\d{1,3}\.?){4})`, https://regex101.com/r/V9agZP/1. You can then fetch your IP from group 1.

Comment: @Avinash: Is it possible to show me how I can cosider it as a column as shared above?

Comment: Sorry @BrainGain, I do not have much knowledge of using `pandas`. But after fetching the IP, you can add like you're doing for other columns.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is unclear to me is how would you assign the same IP for both IDs (005 & 006)? basically, you have some missing data for some of the events.
Other than this, something as simple as the bellow added to your for loop should do the job.

```
with open("data.txt") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for m in pattern.finditer(line):
            key, value = [m.group(i).strip() for i in [1,2]]
            
            if key == "Id":
                if item:
                    data.append(item)
                item = {"Id": value}
            else:
                item[key] = value

        if 'ip[' in line:
            item['ip'] = line.split('ip[')[1]

    data.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df 

Id     Cause    Code    Event Time      Severity    Severity Code   ip
0005    ERROR   307 2020-11-09 10:16:48 WARNING         5           NaN
0006    FAILURE 517 2020-11-09 10:19:47 MINOR           4           10.1.1.1
0007    ERROR   307 2020-11-09 10:16:48 WARNING         5           NaN
0008    FAILURE 517 2020-11-09 10:19:47 MINOR           4           10.1.1.3
```